# Set HEX string as MQ Correlation ID

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to set the correlation ID of my MQ message as this Hex number:
correlationID = "414d51205350434954495f5550493032115bf458a7180410"
It is initially passed as a string to the function

```
        MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
        byte[] corrID = null;
        corrID = Base64.getDecoder().decode(correlationID);
        try 
        {    
            msg.writeString(message);   
            msg.correlationId = corrID;
            queue_con.put(msg,pmo);
            corrID = msg.correlationId;
            System.out.println(corrID);
            System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(corrID));

        }
```

This is 48digits long. I've read that the CorrelationID field can hold 24bytes/48hexadecimal digits. But when I try to set the msg.correlationId field, the number gets truncated to only 32 digits. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Why are you using `base64` encoding? Isn't your string a `hex` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the XML framework part of JRE17:

```
try {
 msg.correlationId = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(correlationID);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
 msg.correlationId = correlationID.getBytes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked:

```
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
        int len = correlationID.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(correlationID.charAt(i), 
16) << 4)
                                 + 
Character.digit(correlationID.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        byte[] corrID = data;
        try 
        {
            msg.writeString(message);   
            msg.correlationId = corrID;
            queue_con.put(msg,pmo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to do the same from pure jms:

```
javax.jms.Message message...
message.setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(new String(value)) );
```